# Problems with div height when viewport of tablet and mobile resolution

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

I have this hover effect of jquery. When I make the browser window small for a tablet or mobile viewport I have adjusted the width but I don't know how to make the height auto. this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/rHJsP/1/embedded/result/

```
general-content-area .team-container .team-box .item {
width:300px;
height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
float:left
 }
```

you can see in this fiddle after making the height 100% in media query after resizing the browser the image container doesn't show
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/rHJsP/2/

Comment: What do you mean with _make the height auto_? It seems to work as intended on my side... Everything stacks up vertically with no problem... And I'm using IE8!!! :| What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

I think  change the css like providing the width and height as % not the px format

```
general-content-area .team-container .team-box .item {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    float:left
}
```

Comment: After the 100% the div container dissapears